# Extracting and storing part of output with shell script

Tags: bash

The `find` command gives me output like

```
a/b/1.xml
a/1.xml
c/d/fd/fg/2.xml
```

I need to write a Bash command to be able to store only data after last `/` in a path.

doing `find . -name "*.xml" >>mayflies.txt`  gives me the full path and stores it, but I need just the `.xml` part to store.

How can I do that? I was trying options like `cut`, but then, due to variable pattern, I got lost on how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `cut` with `rev` to obtain what you want:

```
find . -name "*.xml" | rev | cut -d'/' -f1 | rev >> mayflies.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find . -name '*.xml' -exec basename '{}' \;
```

instead of just printing the result, it executes unix command `basename` to print only file name of what was found.